# Avoid infinite recursion in destructor

Tags: c++, recursion, graph, c++14, destructor

As part of an exercise my university has tasked me with, I have written a small Graph implementation, following this header.

```
class Node {

private:
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Node*> children;

public:
    Node(const std::string& name="");
    virtual ~Node();

}
```

When writing code for the destructor `~Node()`, I noticed that my implementation fails when the graph contains a cycle. This is my implementation so far, which obviously doesn't work if the graph contains a cycle.

```
Node::~Node() {
    for (Node* n : children) {
        delete n;
        n = NULL;
    }
    children.clear();
}
```

I am uncertain as to how I would most elegantly write a destructor that can handle cycles in the graph?

Please note that I was specifically tasked to write a recursive destructor.
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: 1. Don't delete the `children` in `~Node`. 2. Let a higher level function/class manage the destruction of all the `Node`s in the graph.

Comment: It looks like you have an ownership problem. You have shared ownership (multiple objects can have pointers to the same object, and any of them may be responsible for `delete`ing it) as well as potentially circular ownership. This is not a trivial problem. You should change your ownership scheme, store your `Node`s in some sort of `Graph` object, and have only the `Graph` object be responsible for destroying every `Node` it contains. Remember to use `unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers (`std::unique_ptr<T>` vs `T*`) when a pointer own an object.

Comment: *"Please note that I was specifically tasked to write a recursive destructor."* A recursive destructor is a very very poor solution for this kind of problem.

Comment: Note that the `n = NULL` step is completely unnecessary and doesn’t do what you probably intend it to do (but even if it did, e.g. by making the variable type a reference, it would still not be meaningful).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "A recursive destructor is a very very poor solution for this kind of problem" not if the problem is to teach ownership and the perils of recursive destructors. The university is a safe place to experiment with code and understand choices. You want to hit these problems now, not on your job where you have real responsibilities and real consequences.

Comment: @bolov It's still a poor solution for the problem, even if it is a good example of a poor solution. And it's good that OP learns of this now, in case they wouldn't learn it in the university where poor solutions don't have real consequences.

Comment: How much can you change your code?  Can you change the code to disallow cycles?  Can you get rid of raw pointers that may-or-may-not be owning pointers (*Schrödinger's pointers*), because there's no happiness there?

Comment: Nodes in a graph do not have children. (On the map of London Underground, Victoria Station is not a child of Green Park, or vice versa.) They have peers. If you have children, then perhaps your data structure is a rooted tree rather than a graph.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. `Nodes in a graph do not have children.` Nodes in a directed graph do have children. A tree cannot have cycles.

Comment: @eerorika "Nodes in a directed graph do have children" As long as you are content with being your own grandfather perhaps. I do not recall my graph theory textbook applying this word to arbitrary directed graphs. It doesn't make much sense in this setting.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Source and target may be more commonly used terminology (than parent and child) when cycles are allowed. Curiously, programmers often make the (surprisingly) wrong assumption that family trees don't have cycles, making it impossible to represent such rare cases in such wrongly assuming programs.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `children` will be destroyed at the end of the destructor body. Setting its pointers to `NULL` doesn't accomplish anything, and calling `children.clear()` doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: @templatetypedef How come you replaced the C++ tag with C++14?

Comment: You should use nullptr instead of NULL. Don't learn with bad habit.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Complete accident - I hadn’t realized I’d done that!

Answer (score 5):

Option 1: Choose a representation for the graph where nodes are not owned by other nodes, but rather the graph which would be a distinct object. This way the node destructor doesn't need to do anything. <sub>This won't satisfy the requirement of recursion</sub>:

```
struct Graph {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> nodes;
};
```

Note that if there is no inheritance involved, then you could simply use `std::vector<Node>`. I assume that there is, due to the usage of virtual desturctor in `Node`.

Alternatively, you could use another representation for the graph such as adjacency list.

Option 2: Use an algorithm to generate a minimum spanning forest of the graph. Then recursively delete the roots of each spanning tree. You can for example use the Kruskal's algorithm. (Given your representation, it looks like your graph may be connected, in which case there would be only one spaning tree).

Comment: Option three: collect the nodes in a linked list, in any order, disregarding graph edges entirely. Then free the list recursively.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Or perhaps  collect them in a set, so that we don't need another data structure to detect the need to stop the collection in case of a cycle. Also, with a balanced BST, the recursion would actually make sense.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the student could use recursion to print the "done" message at the end of the program and this makes as much sense as anything else. None, that is. In order for a solution to make sense, the problem needs to make sense, and it doesn't. Disclaimer, I am not responsible for opinions of the person whose job is to grade the solution.

Answer (score 3):

One option could be to first create an `unordered_set` of all the `Node*`s and then to `delete` them.

```cpp
void fill(std::unordered_set<Node*>& to_delete, Node* ptr) {
    // try to insert ptr and return if it was already in the set
    if(not to_delete.emplace(ptr).second) return;

    // swap ptr->children with an empty vector
    std::vector<Node*> tmp;
    std::swap(tmp, ptr->children);

    for(Node* c : tmp)       // loop over the pointers
        fill(to_delete, c);  // fill recursively
}

virtual ~Node() noexcept { // std::terminate if anything should throw
    if(children.empty()) return;          // nothing to do here

    std::unordered_set<Node*> to_delete;  // to collect all the Node*'s
    fill(to_delete, this);                // fill the set recursively
    to_delete.erase(this);                // don't delete "this"

    for(auto c : to_delete)               // delete all - they have no children by now
        delete c;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ercoqs4fn)

Comment: Sidenote: `_` is commonly used as a macro for  `gettext`, which is a very widely used library. Thus using it as a variable name can be problematic in larger programs that use such library.

Comment: @eerorika Oh, I'll replace it. I think I got struck by a bit of python when I wrote this :) Thanks.

Comment: You can use `[[maybe_unused]]` to convey the same intention.

Comment: @eerorika Yeah. I went with a C++14 compatible version instead. I don't remember seeing the C++14 tag on the question when I answered - but now it's there.

Comment: there's a serious problem in your code: destructor may throw an exception, and thus may lead to an unexpected program termination

Comment: @icant problem made more obvious

Answer (score 1):

If your graph is a tree (I assume it since your implementation of destructor is valid only for a tree) and you can store parent of the `Node` then you can write iterative version which do not require any extra data structure to avoid recursion.

Also learn to use smart pointers.

```cpp
class Node {

private:
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> children;
    Node* parent;

    void safeCleanClildren();
public:
    Node(std::string name="", Node* parent = nullptr)
        : name{std::move(name)}
    {}

    ~Node() {
       iterativeCleanClildren();
    }

    void addChild(std::string name) {
        children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(node), this);
    }
};

void Node::iterativeCleanClildren()
{
    auto p = this;
    while (!p->children.empty()) {
        while (!p->children.empty()) {
            p = p->back().get(); // go as deep as possible
        }
        if (p != this) {
           p = p->parent; // go back to parent
           p->children.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

How this work?

1. first it finds leaf (right most) in a tree (node which do not have children)
2. Then goes back to parent node and remove child which was just found `p->children.pop_back();` (this destroys `unique_ptr` of just found leaf).
3. Then finds again leaf and so on.
4. This tree clearing continues until root (`this`) node is reached

This way root node ends with no children at all and since it is iterative implementation overflown is impossible. It doesn't matter how much unbalance this tree is.

Comment: Um, how is this code supposed to work? Your inner loop will loop forever in case where the node `A` has only one child, `B`, and the node `B` has only one child, `A`. And if you prohibit creation of such loops, this code is completely redundant.

Comment: If you use smart pointers you could use `shared_ptr`, because multiple nodes seem to share ownership of their common peers/children. And once you use `shared_ptr` there is no need for a manual destructor, I think.

Comment: I've assumed that he has a tree (unique_ptr implies it) - so no cycles in graph. Naive `shared_ptr` is not a solution since it will lead to cycle of strong references and end with memory leak. There is [nice talk from Herb Sutter](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE) about this. He shows his custom container which can handle cycles and garbage collect them. He also mentions stackoverflow issue for list and I just provided answer which handles tree scenario.